# calculated field help, moss 2007

Tags: calculated-column

I'm trying to build a calculated field with the following condition:

```
if [field1], [field2], [field3] = approved

set [field4] = 1

if [field1], [field2], [field3] = denied 

set [field4] = 2

else

set [field4] = 3
```

Any guidence would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for calculated columns is basically the same as Excel. What I usually do is dummy up the formula in Excel and then copy it over, replacing the cell references with column names.

Comment: a sample formula would really help me out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Full reference guide for SharePoint Functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/CH001171117.aspx)

Off the top of my head (haven't tested so could be typos)

Set Field4 as calculated field.

Set its calculation to :- (formatted for easier reading)

```
IF ( OR([field1]="approved",[field2]="approved",[field3]="approved"),
     "1",
     IF ( OR([field1]="denied",[field2]="denied",[field3]="denied"),
          "2",
          "3"
         )
    )
```

For troubleshooting break this down into the constituent parts, (separate out OR and IF) and test each one individually.